# temporary tables within stored procedures on slave servers with readonly set

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, replication, innodb

We have set up a replication scheme master/slave and we've had problems lately because some users wrote directly on the slave instead of the master, making the whole setup inconsistent.

To prevent these problems from happening again, we've decided to remove the insert, delete, update, etc... rights from the users accessing the slave. Problems is that some stored procedure (for reading) require temporary tables.

I read that changing the global variable read_only to true would do what I want and allow the stored procedures to work correctly ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only ) but I keep getting the error :

> The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot
>   execute this statement (1290)

The stored procedure that I used (for testing purpose) is this one :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_readonly` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_readonly`()
BEGIN

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp
(
`BT_INDEX` int(11),
`BT_DESC` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO temp (BT_INDEX, BT_DESC) VALUES (222,'walou'), (111,'bidouille');

DROP TABLE temp;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The create temporary table and the drop table work fine with the readonly flag - if I comment the INSERT line, it runs fine- but whenever I want to insert or delete from that temporary table, I get the error message.

I use Mysql 5.1.29-rc. My default storage engine is InnoDB.

Thanks in advance, this problem is really driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug opened about this for the 6.0 beta:

> http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33669
>
> [3 Jan 2008 19:26] Philip Stoev
>
> Description: When the server is
>   started with --read-only, updates to
>   Falcon temporary tables are not
>   allowed.

You might want to add your findings there.

Comment: yeah, I had seen that, but it seems to be a Falcon specific bug, and I use InnoDB as default storage engine, so I'm not sure this is related.